# How to combine two JSON with extend and return them?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I need to make the following structure:

```
 "rows":[  
    {//panel1  
    },  
    {//panel2  
    }  
    {//panel3 ...   
    }  
  ]
```

So I founded the method [extend](https://techiella.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/underscore-js-extend-vs-jquery-extend/) so I'm trying to do that but it doesn't work because it only returns me the last JSON :

```js
var panel_cpu = {"title": "iNeedHelp","smt": 5}
                 
var panel_swap = {"title": "iNeedHelp2","smt":  6}
                 
var combined = $.extend({}, panel_cpu, panel_swap); 

//following the comments...

var arr = [];
arr.push(panel_cpu);
arr.push(panel_swap);     
////////////////////////////     

//following 1 answer
var combined2 = $.extend({}, [panel_cpu, panel_swap]);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var big_panel = {"rows": arr}

console.log(big_panel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*here is used JQuery because I didn't found the underscore library*

Comment: The merge performed by `$.extend()` is not recursive by default; if a property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second or subsequent object. The values are not merged. This can be seen in the example below by examining the value of banana. However, by passing true for the first function argument, objects will be recursively merged. [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Comment: You are not merging objects at all, what you are expecting is collection i.e. multiple objects in an array. You should be using `[].push`

Comment: @Rayon put an answer because you are right :)

Comment: Up voted your question to support your research effort. :)

Comment: @Inuka thanks I appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve the output as follows:

```js
var panel_cpu = [{
  "title": "iNeedHelp",
  "smt": 5
}]

var panel_swap = [{
  "title": "iNeedHelp2",
  "smt": 6
}]

var combined = panel_cpu.concat(panel_swap);

var big_panel = [{
  "rows": [combined]
}]

console.log(big_panel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However you need to have array values for `panel_cpu` and `panel_swqp` variables. I will work on a simple answer while posting this.

**Edit 1**

Changing this would get the output as follows,

```
var big_panel = {
  "rows": combined
}
```

```js
var panel_cpu = [{
  "title": "iNeedHelp",
  "smt": 5
}]

var panel_swap = [{
  "title": "iNeedHelp2",
  "smt": 6
}]

var combined = panel_cpu.concat(panel_swap);

var big_panel = {
  "rows": combined
}

console.log(big_panel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you look the result it's `"rows":[[..` but I need `"rows":[...`

Comment: so yes now it's ok :) I just don't know if I should mark your answer as the answer because @Rayon was the first one but in comments, so if he didn't put an answer I'll mark yours. I up vote your answer [edit] arrrg I need to have 15pts to up vote

Comment: Decide yourself which one is the best solution for you buddy. I would say comments are acceptable as answers too but mark the correct working solution if somebody posted that for you. In your case as you said wait for @Rayon to post his comment as an answer. :)